# How to spawn a background program with execv

Tags: c++, process, fork, execv

I am using fork and execv to spawn child programs. How can I make these programs run in the background? I tried not waiting for them, but they still send output to the screen.

Comment: What's your definition of "background"?

Comment: Running a process in the background is the same thing as program &.

Comment: your terminology is not consistent - `program&` will still write its output to the screen, "background" in this case is just releasing the shell prompt. `program > /dev/null&` will do what you want

Comment: No it won't. `top &` will not show anything on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Redirect stdout/stderr to `/dev/null` before you exec:

```
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stdout);
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
exec....
```

Comment: I get this error: cannot convert ‘FILE*’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’

Comment: @z-buffer: I swapped some arguments, corrected the answer now.

Comment: How would the output be put back to normal?

Comment: @z-buffer: "back to normal"? If you want to hide/discard output, redirect it to /dev/null as above. exec will never return anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipe to redirect output of child process. Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679006/why-cant-get-data-from-tail-f) queston. There is code what doing redirection of stdout and stderr to pipe.